Can I use "fix up" for people's appearances?
According to OD:

fix up: to repair, decorate or make something ready

Can I use it for people's appearances? For instance:

Q: When do you use a mirror?
A: Whenever I need to fix up my appearance.

I've tried searching for it on many sites but didn't see any examples so I'm not sure if it's used this way.

I've tried searching for it on many sites but didn't see any examples so I'm not sure if it's used this way. Can you explain this because I can find lots of Google hits for "fix up my appearance".

@StuartF - a Google search using quotes for things like "fix myself up in the mirror" (or himself/herself) produces a limited number of examples, mainly from low-prestige or informal sources like fan-fiction, self-published material, Reddit, etc.

There are lots of written instances of I just need to fix my hair and a few of I just need to fix my face. To me, they all sound rather "lower-class, uneducated" (or facetious imitation thereof). I don't think many middle-class Brits would use the word fix like this. It's reminiscent of US "trailer-trash" style "If you stay the night I'll fix you some breakfast'".

So what's your suggestion to replace "fix up" here? I'm a guy and I don't want a phrase which makes me sound girly. I just want to say that there're occasions when I need to look good/presentable, when my girlfriend's parents visit me for example, and that's when I need a mirror.

@AnIELTSLearner - if I said 'I need to fix up my stubble' and got out my electric shaver, I don't believe anyone (who was not a damned fool) would call me 'girly'.

You want to check your appearance just to be sure there isn't anything that needs 'fixing'.

Thank you all for your suggestions. By the way, do you guys have the same feeling about "fix up" as FumbleFingers does? Because @Jay seems to find it okay.

Well, as a "middle-class Brit" I might use it for repairing a machine, but not for tidying my hair and the like.

"You want to check your appearance just to be sure there isn't anything that needs 'fixing'." => Can we condense the part after "appearance" in some way?

"Gentlemen - please adjust your dress before leaving"

If fhis is a phrase request, ask it in that way from the get-go, instead of asking whether it  is possible to use a phrase in a certain context wthout providing the reason for wanting to know.  Your actual question:  How does a guy say, in a non-girly way, that he needs to  examine himself in the mirror to make sure he is presentable?

Yes, you can use "fix up" in a cosmetic context, yourself in front of the mirror, but be aware that when using a term outside its usual domain it brings the odor of that domain along with it, so to speak.
If you use it of yourself in front of the mirror, it is as though you're speaking of yourself as an object that needs some "touching up".  That could be taken as self-deprecating humor, toilette as repair shop.
Compare:

I have to go in for some exploratory surgery. The doctors need to look under the hood.


Yes. Usually this would be used if you're talking about "fixing my make-up" or "fixing my hair". It only makes sense if you're actually "fixing" something, that is, correcting something that is wrong. You wouldn't use the word "fixing", for example, to refer to getting dressed in general. Well, unless you had noticed or someone pointed out a defect in how you were dressed. Like, "My wife told me that my tie was not tied correctly, so I went to a mirror to fix it."

I noticed that you used "fix", not "fix up" in all of your examples. But I'm asking about "fix up", so I'm not sure if you misread my question or it's just that they mean the same thing.

Adding up after fix rarely if ever affects the meaning - it's just an optional "flourish" to a general-purpose verb. Compare "Please make [up] a packed lunch for me"

The combination 'fix up' by itself suggests match-making tome.

@AnIELTSLearner Oh, sorry, I was a little sloppy. But yes, everything I said applies to "fix up" just as well as to "fix". In general "fix up" means the same as "fix" ... I can't think of an example where they'd really mean something different but maybe it's just not occurring to me.

@bradimus Yes, if someone says, "I can fix you up with Sally", that means, "arrange a date". But you could also say, "I can fix up your hair style", etc. Depends on context.

"Fix up my appearance" sounds unidiomatic to me, I think because of the mismatch between the casual 'fix up' and formal/Latinate 'appearance'. More idiomatic might be 'fix up the way I look' or even 'fix up my look' but I wouldn't say these are common phrases.
Most phrases relating to appearance that I can think of sound a little weird with 'fix up', but 'fix' on its own is definitely used.
For example, an informal (UK only?) phrase that I would most associate with a middle-aged woman speaker is 'I need to fix my face' referring to needing to touch up her make-up. (Or more dialectically, 'I need to fix me face'.) Saying 'Fix up my face' is just about possible, but from a non-native speaker I think it would be interpreted as a mistake.
I would say this is not a phrase used by younger generations though, or if so, it would be heavily ironic, with the subtext that 'this is what mums say'.
'Fix my hair' is more common and neutral though. Like the phrase above, using 'fix up', meaning 'tidy (up)', in these instances is to me in the grey area of acceptable from a native speaker but otherwise would be likely interpreted as an error. Otherwise 'fix up my hair' could be used to mean 'tie/pin up my hair' or could just maybe mean 'put my hair in a fancy hair-do (for an event)'.

Just saw OP's comment about looking for a phrase usually associated with a man! In that case, unlike another commenter, I could see myself using the phrase '[Yikes is that what I look like?] I need to fix myself up', which I hadn't thought of. Other potential phrases are 'I need to smarten myself up / tidy myself up' or likely be more specific, with 'fix my hair / shave / put on some fresh clothes / etc'.
